Azure Connection String not readable in Spring Boot application.properties
I have a Java Spring Boot app deployed on Microsoft Azure that is connected to a PostgreSQL database. I want to connect to the database using credentials stored in Azure as Connection strings. The problem is that when the app is starting, it fails because the environment variable is not valid.
In Azure, I configured a connection string called DBCONN_IP with "Custom" type. As the documentation says, this will be available as environment variable called CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_IP in app.
In application.properties I have the following:
database.ip = ${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_IP:localhost}
When application starts, the connection is refused, because the environment  variable is not valid and it replaces it with localhost, therefore the application is not started at all.
However, I added a simple controller that just returns the value of another environment variable set as a connection string:
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        try {
            String envString = System.getenv("CUSTOMCONNSTR_TEST_ENV_VARIABLE");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(envString, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }

This works and the correct value is returned.
My question is why the connection string accessed in application.properties is invalid?
Should I set something else in Azure or am I missing something?
L.E:
application.properties looks like:
database.ip = ${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_IP}
database.port = ${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PORT}
database.user = ${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_USER}
database.password = ${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD}
database.name = ${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_DBNAME}

spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://${database.ip}:${database.port}/${database.name}
spring.datasource.username = ${database.user}
spring.datasource.password = ${database.password}

o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true

2024-07-14T11:59:34.099Z  INFO 6468 --- [parcelroes] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 



Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
============================
2024-07-14T11:59:34.130Z ERROR 6468 --- [parcelroes] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT

============================
***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************
Positive matches:

-----------------
Description:


    None
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String:



    Property: spring.datasource.password
Negative matches:
    Value: "${database.password}"
-----------------
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 15:30

    Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD' in value "${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD}"
    None


Action:


Exclusions:
Update your application's configuration
-----------


2024-07-14T11:59:34.130Z  WARN 6468 --- [parcelroes] [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] to prepare test instance [com.thpsw.parcelroes.ParcelroesApplicationTests@664632e9]
    None


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@306c7bf6 testClass = com.thpsw.parcelroes.ParcelroesApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.thpsw.parcelroes.ParcelroesApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2584b82d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@626abbd0, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@798162bc, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@24959ca4, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@dedde0e7], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180) ~[spring-test-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
Unconditional classes:
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
----------------------
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191) ~[spring-test-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]

    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    None
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]

    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true


those are 2 different variables: 1.CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_IP and 2. CUSTOMCONNSTR_TEST_ENV_VARIABLE

Yes, indeed. In the first phase, I tried only with CUSTOMCONNSTR_TEST_ENV_VARIABLE in the controller and it worked. Then, I added a new connection string to establish the db connection. The point is why it worked in code, but not in application.properties

why don't u try printing out the correct variable CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_IP and see which value is being returned?

Just did it now. It prints the right value set in Azure. However, the connection to DB is still refused if I try to access this env variable in application.properties

That doesn't make any sense. I would suggest to remove :localhost part so that it connects with the correct value and see what the error message is, in the logs

I edited the original question with the application.properties and the error returned.

thanks, please provide complete log (not just one sentence)

I have just added it.

the actual issue is in this line: Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD' in value "${CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD}" Meaning CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD is not set. Since it got down to this property line, we can assume that the previous 3 properties (CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_IP, CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PORT and CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_USER) are fine

I have checked again. CUSTOMCONNSTR_DBCONN_PWD is present in Azure, but still doesn't work. I have also changed its name and deployed again, but even with a different name, it doesn't work...
